# SonarQube 4.1 + Teamcity - Unit Tests Coverage 0.0% Unit test success 100.0%

Tags: maven, sonarqube

We use maven sonar plugin on a Teamcity build directory to analyze our java build.
Everything looks good Except unit test coverage.

The dashboards show the coverage at 0% and success at 100% for unit tests.

Any pointers ?

SonarQube 4.1

Comment: Same occurs when running sonar-runner in a Gradle build.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, you should run **mvn clean install** previous to sonar task

**mvn clean install sonar:sonar**

Add the following configuration in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>                                   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0.201210061924</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                        <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.0.201210061924</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Step1. Teamcity Project 1 runs the maven build - that takes care of mvn clean install and also executes junits. The junits are run in this build step and TEST.xml reports generated Step2. Teamcity Project 1 triggers Project 2 which is another script.. it executes mvn sonar:sonar... It correctly reads unit test pass rate and shows on dashboard... However the unit test coverage information is not read and shows as 0%

Comment: I have edited my answer... Can you try with that config and tell me the results?